# How to constrain movement within the area of a circle

Tags: javascript, geometry

This might be more a geometry related question, but I'm trying to constrain a controller within an area of a circle. I know I have to touch the Math.sin() and Math.cos() methods, but my attemps so far have been fruitless so far.

[image]

Here is the jsfiddle:
So far I've been able to constrain it to an invisible square. http://jsfiddle.net/maGVK/

Comment: you need to ensure x^2 + y^2 <= r^2, r  being the radius of the circle. No need to use trigononmetric functions for such a simple task.

Comment: I have updated your fiddle to this: http://jsfiddle.net/vJHZz/35/ - i am not a math wiz so i have tried a bruteforce approach to finding a valid x/y combo. It is not finished but i am out of time. I hope you can use it as a jump of point to get to your solution - the goal being to get rid of the safety net in the loop (the break clause) - happy coding ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So I finally was able to complete this with a bit of everyone's help.

```
var pointerEl = document.getElementById("pointer");
var canvasEl = document.getElementById("canvas");
var canvas = {
    width: canvasEl.offsetWidth,
    height: canvasEl.offsetHeight,
    top: canvasEl.offsetTop,
    left: canvasEl.offsetLeft
};
canvas.center = [canvas.left + canvas.width / 2, canvas.top + canvas.height / 2];
canvas.radius = canvas.width / 2;


window.onmousemove = function(e) {
    var result = limit(e.x, e.y);
        pointer.style.left = result.x + "px";
        pointer.style.top = result.y + "px";
}

function limit(x, y) {
    var dist = distance([x, y], canvas.center);
    if (dist <= canvas.radius) {
        return {x: x, y: y};
    } 
    else {
        x = x - canvas.center[0];
        y = y - canvas.center[1];
        var radians = Math.atan2(y, x)
           return {
               x: Math.cos(radians) * canvas.radius + canvas.center[0],
               y: Math.sin(radians) * canvas.radius + canvas.center[1]
           }
        } 
    }

function distance(dot1, dot2) {
    var x1 = dot1[0],
        y1 = dot1[1],
        x2 = dot2[0],
        y2 = dot2[1];
    return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x1 - x2, 2) + Math.pow(y1 - y2, 2));
}
```

You can see the result here:

http://jsfiddle.net/7Asn6/

Answer (score 1):

```
var pointerEl = document.getElementById("pointer");
var canvasEl = document.getElementById("canvas");
var canvas = {
    width: canvasEl.offsetWidth,
    height: canvasEl.offsetHeight,
    top: canvasEl.offsetTop,
    left: canvasEl.offsetLeft
};
canvas.center = [canvas.left + canvas.width / 2, canvas.top + canvas.height / 2];
canvas.radius = canvas.width / 2;


window.onmousemove = function(e) {
    var result = limit(e.x, e.y);
    if (!result.limit) {
        pointer.style.left = result.x + "px";
        pointer.style.top = result.y + "px";
    }
}

function limit(x, y) {
    var dist = distance([x, y], canvas.center);
    if (dist <= canvas.radius) {
        return {x: x, y: y};
    } else {
        return {limit: true};
    }
}

function distance(dot1, dot2) {
    var x1 = dot1[0],
        y1 = dot1[1],
        x2 = dot2[0],
        y2 = dot2[1];
    return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x1 - x2, 2) + Math.pow(y1 - y2, 2));
}
```

this could do the work, though the movement is not smooth....that will need more geometry knowledge...
fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cRxMa/

Comment: Thanks a lot! I really do need the dot to "follow" the cursor even if it's not over the circle, I'll try reading up on some geometry.

Answer (score 1):

This arithmetic is trivial as long as you ***normalize*** each data point (prospective position), which i have tried to do in the function below:

```
function locatePoint(canvas_size, next_position) {
    // canvas_size & next_position are both 2-element arrays
    // (w, h) & (x, y)
    dist = function(x, y) {
        return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x, 2) + Math.pow(y, 2));
    };
    x = next_position[0];
    y = next_position[1];
    rescaledX = x/(canvas_size[0]/2);
    rescaledY = y/(canvas_size[1]/2);
    if (distance(x, y) <= 1) {
    // the base case; position is w/in the circle
    } 
    else {
    // position is outside the circle, so perhaps
    // do something like random select a new position, then
    // call this function again (recursively) passing in 
    // that new position
    }   
}
```

so in the simple diagram below, i have just inscribed a unit circle (r=1) inside a square whose sides are r*2. Your canvas dimensions *do not* have to be square though. To further simplify the calculation, you only need to consider *one* of the four quadrants--the upper right quadrant, let's say. The reason is that the Euclidean distance formula squares each coordinate value, so negative values become positive.

Put another way, the simplest way is to imagine a circle inscribed in your canvas and whose center is also the center of your canvas (so (0, 0) is the *center* not the upper left-hand corner); next, both canvas and circle are *shrunk* until the circle has radius = 1. Hopefully i have captured this in the function above.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. Within the `else` statement (cursor is outside circle), would it be a good strategy to find the angle between the cursor and the center and place the dot along the circumference of the circle at the corresponding angle?

Comment: i suppose you could but it's much easier to e.g., multiply the coordinate pair by some discount factor (less than one) and then evaluate this new pair by the distance function. I am assuming you don't really care where you put the cursor within the circle, just that it's inside somewhere.

Comment: I'd need it to lie at the edge of the circle, as if it was following the cursor.

Comment: so the coordinate pairs that lie along the edge of the unit circle are given by x = cos(theta) and y = sin(theta); theta is measured counter-clockwise, starting at (1, 0) on the unit circle.

Answer (score 0):

Hi and thanks for sharing your solution.

Your jsfiddle helps me a lot to constraint the movement of a rotation handle.

Here's my solution using jQuery :

```js
function getBall(xVal, yVal, dxVal, dyVal, rVal, colorVal) {
  var ball = {
    x: xVal,
    lastX: xVal,
    y: yVal,
    lastY: yVal,
    dx: dxVal,
    dy: dyVal,
    r: rVal,
    color: colorVal,
    normX: 0,
    normY: 0
  };

  return ball;
}

var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var xLabel = document.getElementById("x");
var yLabel = document.getElementById("y");
var dxLabel = document.getElementById("dx");
var dyLabel = document.getElementById("dy");

var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var containerR = 200;
canvas.width = containerR * 2;
canvas.height = containerR * 2;
canvas.style["border-radius"] = containerR + "px";

var balls = [
  getBall(containerR, containerR * 2 - 30, 2, -2, 20, "#0095DD"),
  getBall(containerR, containerR * 2 - 50, 3, -3, 30, "#DD9500"),
  getBall(containerR, containerR * 2 - 60, -3, 4, 10, "#00DD95"),
  getBall(containerR, containerR * 2 / 5, -1.5, 3, 40, "#DD0095")
];

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  for (var i = 0; i < balls.length; i++) {
    var curBall = balls[i];
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(curBall.x, curBall.y, curBall.r, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.fillStyle = curBall.color;
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
    curBall.lastX = curBall.x;
    curBall.lastY = curBall.y;
    curBall.x += curBall.dx;
    curBall.y += curBall.dy;
    var dx = curBall.x - containerR;
    var dy = curBall.y - containerR;
    var distanceFromCenter = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);

    if (distanceFromCenter >= containerR - curBall.r) {
      var normalMagnitude = distanceFromCenter;
      var normalX = dx / normalMagnitude;
      var normalY = dy / normalMagnitude;
      var tangentX = -normalY;
      var tangentY = normalX;
      var normalSpeed = -(normalX * curBall.dx + normalY * curBall.dy);
      var tangentSpeed = tangentX * curBall.dx + tangentY * curBall.dy;
      curBall.dx = normalSpeed * normalX + tangentSpeed * tangentX;
      curBall.dy = normalSpeed * normalY + tangentSpeed * tangentY;
    }

    xLabel.innerText = "x: " + curBall.x;
    yLabel.innerText = "y: " + curBall.y;
    dxLabel.innerText = "dx: " + curBall.dx;
    dyLabel.innerText = "dy: " + curBall.dy;
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

draw();
```

```css
canvas { background: #eee; }
```

```html
<div id="x"></div>
<div id="y"></div>
<div id="dx"></div>
<div id="dy"></div>
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

Hope this help someone.

Comment: Your answer is irrelevant to the question. Greetings from future)

Comment: Did you take a look at the code I provided in my jsFiddle before saying my response is irrelevant ? Just compare my code (especially `limit` and `distance` functions) and the code that gives @Duopixel in his response. I'm glad to gives him the inspiration to responds himself to his own question.

Comment: The fiddle is great. But it doesn't contain neither moving inside a circle nor  a moving dot (little circle conditions differs from little square conditions). Sorry but true. It is not a crime nevertheless and it can be useful to someone. Crime answers are ought to be downvoted)