# Limit element to a round container outline on mousemove

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouse, coordinates

I have a little div which I set up to follow my mouse but still being limited to a parent div dimensions. This is the [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/AlphaCrack/7km9rfy2/).

Here is the script that I use to make the follower div follow the mouse and limit to the parent's size. The full code can be seen in the fiddle.

```
var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0, limitX = $('.container').width()-15, limitY = $('.container').height()-15;
$(window).mousemove(function(e){
var offset = $('.container').offset();
var halfContWidth = $('.container').width()/2;
var halfContHeight = $('.container').height()/2;
mouseX = Math.min(e.pageX - offset.left, limitX);
mouseY = Math.min(e.pageY - offset.top, limitY);
if (mouseX < 0) mouseX = 0;
if (mouseY < 0) mouseY = 0;
$('.log').html("DivX: " + Math.round(mouseX - halfContWidth) + " DivY: " + Math.round(mouseY - halfContHeight));
});

$(window).resize(function(){
    limitX = $('.container').width()-15;
    limitY = $('.container').height()-15;
});


// cache the selector
var follower = $("#follower");
var xp = 0, yp = 0;
var loop = setInterval(function(){
// change 12 to alter damping higher is slower
xp += (mouseX - xp) / 12;
yp += (mouseY - yp) / 12;
follower.css({left:xp, top:yp});

},5);
```

But what if I want the limiter div round with border radius and still have my mouse follower limited to its round outline? [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/AlphaCrack/vnv5ydvc/6/)

Comment: Do you want the mouse movement to be only in the container and not the whole page?

Comment: Yes. only in the ".container" div as in the first fiddle.

Comment: does the round shaped container have to be resizable?

Comment: Yes. I need it to be responsive to the browser's dimensions as it is now.

Comment: On this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515900/how-to-constrain-movement-within-the-area-of-a-circle , the first answer has a working solution that might be adjustable to work with a resizeable container.

Comment: Is not what I need. Look at @Raeen Hashemi's answer from this post and at comments. He's answer does exactly what that script from your link does but I need something more than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the mouse movement to be only in the `container` div, change the `$(window).mousemove` to:

```
$('.container').mousemove...
```

Here's the fiddle for both conditions: [Rectangle](http://jsfiddle.net/7km9rfy2/1/) [Circle](http://jsfiddle.net/vnv5ydvc/7/)

**EDIT:**

I used the Pythagoras’ equation and implemented this part of code:

```
if (Math.sqrt(Math.pow(Math.abs(e.pageX - offset.left - halfContWidth), 2) + Math.pow(Math.abs(e.pageY - offset.top - halfContHeight), 2)) > newDim / 2) {

        var ratio = (mouseX - halfContWidth)/(mouseY - halfContHeight);
        var sign = 1;

        if(mouseX - halfContWidth < 0)
            sign = -1;

        mouseX = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(ratio,2)*Math.pow(newDim,2)/4/(1+Math.pow(ratio,2))) * sign;            
        mouseY = (mouseX/ratio);

        mouseX += halfContWidth;
        mouseY += halfContHeight;

    }
```

It checks if the mouse position is outside the circle, then it changes the position of the cursor in the circle accordingly. I used the equation like this: `(newDim/2)^2 = (mouseX)^2 + (mouseY)^2`

Here's the fiddle: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hg21ce45/1/)

**EDIT:** updated fiddle with pointing mouse cursor in the middle of red cursor adding `5` to `xp += (mouseX - xp - 5)` => [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hg21ce45/2/)

Comment: This is not what I need. I dont know if you saw but even when I move the mouse outside the container, the follower still follow the mouse position, but it's limited to container's outline. But thanks for your answer.

Comment: What do you expect it to do? Do you want the red cursor to disappear?

Comment: No no. I don't know how to make you understand what I want. I want it to make the same thing as in the Rectangle but not being limited to a square shape. I want it limited to the round shape. When I have my mouse outside the container I want the red pointer to follow the round contour not a square one.