# Reducing area of div to a circle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

While giving a div equal height and width and setting a border radius of 100% makes a div "look" like a circle, the reality is that it is still a square in disguise. How can I make a div a "true" circle? For my purpose, I want to make items droppable only within the circle I create. By making a div look like a circle, items are still droppable outside of the circle at the edges.

```js
$(".circle").droppable();
$(".drop").draggable({
  containment: "parent"
  });
```

```css
.circle
{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}
.drop
{
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}
.drop:hover
{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="circle">
<div class="drop">
  Drop Me<br>
  Outside
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You will have to use an SVG in the form of a circle. CSS-Tricks has a good tutorial: https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/

In an SVG, each node and line is an element that can be targeted, positioned, and interacted with instead of being the pseudo circle of a square div with the borders rounded.

Comment: The above comment is correct. With CSS the best you could do is use `clip-path` to clip the element into a circle but I just tried a sample and even with clip-path it exhibits the same behavior as in question. You'd probably have to do some calculations using the circle's radius to find points along its circumference, see the points that the droppable box have and then act accordingly.

Comment: Have you read the answers?

Answer (score 0):

```
overflow: hidden;
box-sizing: border-box;
padding: 50px;
```

for container would do the thing :)
or if you can do it with flexbox then

```
overflow: hidden;
box-sizing: border-box;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
```

use svg object like this, as suggested in comment

```
<svg class="circle" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100"><circle fill="#FFF" cx="50" cy="50" r="50"/></svg>
```

Comment: This does not solve his problem. The div will still be treated as though it is a square for drag/drop (you will still be able to drop in the invisible corners of the div which is what he does not want). Have to use an SVG if you want the element to be treated as a true circle. Rounding a div only alters the visuals - it does not make the actual div round.

Answer (score 0):

I can propose to handle dragging manually and prevent unexpected behaviour if an element goes out of a circle. Add some additional javascript.

The following code can deal with just one corner (left-top). You can add three more conditions to handle all corners. It would be better to move a small circle rather than a rectangle - a circle has just one condition, rectangle has four ones.

```js
// radius of a circle
var radius = 100;

$(".circle").droppable();
$(".drop").draggable({
  containment: "parent",
  drag: function( event, ui ) {
    // position of a left top corner of a rectangle with respect 
    // to a center of a circle 
    var x = ui.position.left - radius,
        y = radius - ui.position.top,
        r = Math.sqrt(x*x + y*y);

    // if distance from a center of a circle is greater than radius
    // move it back into the circle
    if (Math.floor(r) > radius) {
        ui.position.top = radius - Math.round(radius * y / r);
        ui.position.left = Math.round(radius * x / r) + radius;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.circle
{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}
.drop
{
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}
.drop:hover
{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="circle">
<div class="drop">
  Drop Me<br>
  Outside
</div>
</div>
```

UPD. Example of dragging circle was considered [in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515900/how-to-constrain-movement-within-the-area-of-a-circle).