# Prevent cursor from entering certain area while rotating element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jQuery rotatable to rotate an element on the page.

However, I would like to prevent the user from dragging the cursor towards the center of the element. In essence, the mouse pointer should slide along a circle centered on the center of the target element when the user tries to drag towards the center.

```
$('.element').rotatable({
    handle: $('.element .handle'),
    start: function( event, ui ) {
        rotate_in_progress = true;
    },
    stop: function( event, ui ) {
        rotate_in_progress = false;
    },
    rotate: function( event, ui ) {
        //current mouse position
  var mouse_pos = {
            "x": event.clientX,
            "y": event.clientY
        };
  var element_center = {
    "x": parseInt($('.element').css("left")) + 0.5 * parseInt($('.element').css("width")),
    "y": parseInt($('.element').css("top")) + 0.5 * parseInt($('.element').css("height"))
  };
  console.log(mouse_pos,element_center);
        //TODO prevent mouse from moving within 20px of the center of the element; slide it along the edge of a circle with radius = 20px around the center in this case
    }
});
```

Current fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Lqrpsp53/8/

Comment: You'll have to create a function that takes your center and the current position of the mouse(which you'll get in the callback to the eventListener). Then using these, create a line using the equation: http://www.mathwarehouse.com/algebra/linear_equation/write-equation/equation-of-line-given-two-points.php and on this line get a point at the distance equal to your radius(you have 2 equations, one for line and one for circle). Finally set the current mouse position to this point.

Comment: @ayushgp "Set the current mouse position"? How?! There is no way to do this in Javascript. If there was, this question wouldn't exist.

Comment: Yes I also checked that later that time. Forgot to update that here. I guess another way to go about this would be to use a custom pointer, so that you override the mouse pointer(This is just to give a consistent experience to the user). Whenever the mouse moves inside the circle, hide the actual pointer, set up an extra pointer image at the point where it entered the div. Doing this for a circle would be difficult as HTML follows a block model. According to the movement of actual mouse, move this image accordingly.

Comment: This might help with the rect-circle problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515900/how-to-constrain-movement-within-the-area-of-a-circle

Comment: The point is that I need to keep the actual mouse away from the center of the circle because the rotations become jumpy and unpredictable around the center. So a bogus image being displayed as a pointer while the actual mouse goes around the central circle flipping the element left and right really would be counterproductive to the user experience.

Comment: I think you should create an issue on the library page as they'll be better able to assist you with what you're trying to achieve.